# Javascript returning incorrect value from a Javascript object property

Tags: javascript, html, json, properties

So, I have an array of Javascipt objects, that contain extra properties and information corresponding to the items in a `select` element.

When the user selects an element in the dropdown, it looks the item up in the Javascipt array, and is supposed to populate two other fields on the page with the relevant values from the corresponding Javascipt object.

Here is the js function:

```
    function pickedCode(who) {
        who = $(who);
        var opt = who.find(':selected');
        var val = opt.val();

        for (lc = 0; lc < codes.length; lc++) {
            var code = codes[lc];
            if (code.Id == val) {
                var amt = code.Dollars;
                alert(code.Dollars)
                $('input[field=amount]').val((amt > 0 ? amt : ''));
                $('textarea[field=text]').val(code.Text);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

... here is the HTML where it is calling the function:

```
<select onchange="pickedCode(this);" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstCodes" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstCodes">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="70">3-DAY NOTICE</option>
    <option value="156">A-ABSOLUTE TRANSCRIPT</option>
    <option value="47">ABORTED EVICTION</option>
    <option value="204">ACCESS AGREEMENT</option>
    <option value="174">ADD'L SERVES/MAILINGS</option>
    <option value="124">AFF IN OPP - COMMERCIAL</option>
</select>
```

... and here is the array of Javascipt data:

```
var codes = [{
        "Id": 70,
        "Code": "3-DAY NOTICE",
        "Text": "Initiation of Non-Payment Proceeding.",
        "Dollars": "46.20"
    }, {
        "Id": 156,
        "Code": "A-ABSOLUTE TRANSCRIPT",
        "Text": "A-ABSOLUTE TRANSCRIPT",
        "Dollars": "0.00"
    }, {
        "Id": 47,
        "Code": "ABORTED EVICTION",
        "Text": "THE MARSHAL HAD TO ABORT TODAY'S SCHEDULED EVICTION AS ",
        "Dollars": "0.00"
    }, {
        "Id": 204,
        "Code": "ACCESS AGREEMENT",
        "Text": "ACCESS AGREEMENT",
        "Dollars": "0.00"
    }, {
        "Id": 174,
        "Code": "ADD'L SERVES/MAILINGS",
        "Text": "ADD'L MAILINGS",
        "Dollars": "0.00"
    }, {
        "Id": 124,
        "Code": "AFF IN OPP - COMMERCIAL",
        "Text": "Aff in Opp - COMMERCIAL",
        "Dollars": "85.05"
    }
]
```

It is looking up and finding the proper element.
It is getting the text and setting it into the textarea properly.

The problem is with the property `Dollars`. For some reason it is always returning a value of `"0.00"` for the `Dollars` property, even for the items which have an amount greater than 0, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Originally, it was named `Amount`; I thought maybe that was a reserved word or something, so I changed it to `Dollars`. I also originally had it as an actual number, instead of a string, and still had the same problem (then it always returned `0`). I thought maybe it was a problem in assigning it to the variable, so I alerted the actual property itself instead of the variable (the alert is just for debugging), but the property directly is returning 0.

I also thought maybe it was a type issue when checking the `code.Id == val`, but that can't be the issue, because it is actually finding the right item and getting the property text from it.

I found a couple other questions on here that were similar, but they all seemed to be related to the property itself being an array and the user not indexing into the property. Mine are not arrays though, the individual properties are all just straight up values.

I've tried this in both Firefox (57.0) and Google Chrome (62.0.3202.94) and even tried Opera (49.0.2725.47), and I get the same results in all three browsers.

Just to truly confuse myself, I decided to step through the client-side debugger in Firefox and see what happens. When viewing the source of the page, it clearly has the value of 46.2:
[image]

However when stepping through the function, and looking at the variables, when it pulls out that code from the array, it is loading a value of 0.00 into memory: 
[image]

So, yeah... now I'm completely confused about what is going on, since the values it is loading into memory do not match the actual source. I did a search through the code to make sure the... and BAH! Looking at the screenshot sparked a thought and I figured it out. Details to come in an answer, for posterity.

Comment: [That isn't JSON!](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vusiqupiru/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Replaced all occurances of JSON with Javascript for accuracy.

Comment: try do var amt = parseFloat(code.Dollars);

Comment: Pretty surely you want your dollars to be numbers, not strings.

Comment: @AmitWagner thanks; just tried that. Still no luck. Then it just returns 0 instead of 
"0.00".

Comment: @Bergi - yes, as stated I originally was passing it back as a number; the only difference was that then it got `0` instead of `"0.00"`. I had changed it to a string in an attempt to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sparked in my thought process and figured this out as a combination of @sandy_22's comments and the screenshots from the Javascript debugger.

The array being held in code was assigned from the code-behind using a literal. such as
`var codes = <asp:literal id="ltlCodes" runat="server"/>` .

When changing one of the other dropdowns on the page, it would, through AJAX, rebind the literal based on the selected client (different clients have different fee amounts).

This all worked fine, and it would update the literal, the source got updated appropriately, and when I did a `View Source` I would see the updated array.

It did NOT however cause Javascript to reload the new array into the `codes` variable. So even though the source code showed the right array data, the in-memory variable itself still held the original copy of the data.

I took out the literal, so the client side code just became `var codes = null;` .
Then in server-side, when switching clients, and rebinding the codes, I now update them with a Javascript snippet as so:
`AjaxManager.ResponseScripts.Add("codes = " & linqForNewArray() & ";")` .
This way the in-memory variable actually gets updated, and now it all works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Please try replacing  var amt = code.Dollars;  with below:

```
var amt = Number(code.Dollars);
```

Comment: No joy. Tried it as both `Number(...)` and `new Number(...)`. Either way, it still comes out as `0`.